# How to jump to another method?

Tags: java

Is there any function in java that lets you jump to another method?
This is an example how it should work:

```
if (boolean expression(){
    jump to public void something;
    if (boolean expression) {
        jump to public void something2;
    } else{
        jump to public void 3;
    }
```

This is needed for a program that checks 3 numbers, and they have different methods linked to them.

Comment: what do you mean by "jump"?

Comment: Well, I mean it has to jump in the program to another place (which is the method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by jump, you mean calling a method:

```
   if (boolean expression(){
        something();
        if (boolean expression(){
            something2();
        }
        else{
            something3();
        }
```

Comment: A method in Java cannot start with a digit, not even as an example.

Comment: I knew I was close with that one! Thanks for the tip, I won't forget it!

Answer (score 2):

Simply invoke it, in your example

```
if (boolean expression(){
    something();
} else if (boolean expression(){
    something2();
} else{
    something3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `jump to public void something` just call `something()`

Answer (score 0):

if you have the mothod call in the class just call the method like

```
something(int i);
```

if your method is in another class make sure you have an object of that class if the method isn't static and call your method

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.something(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax called "jump to" although you can easily call a method by firstly making a method.

```
public void myMethod(){
 // do something
}
```

now when you have done this, you call it from another method by invoking it's name `myMethod();`. You might know that a method can either return a variable or return nothing (void) if you give it a return-type you MUST return a variable with the same type as your method.
For example:

```
public int oneplusone(){
int integer = 1 + 1;
return integer;
}
```

and a void would be like this:

```
public void oneplusone(){
int integer = 1 + 1;
System.out.println(integer);
}
```

When you've specified your method you need to call it by invoking its name from another place in your program. Final example:

```
public class Snippet(){

public static void main(String args[]){ // THIS IS THE MAIN METHOD OF YOUR PROGRAM!
Snippet snippet = new Snippet();
System.out.println(snippet.oneplusone());
}

public int oneplusone(){
int integer = 1 + 1;
return integer;
}
}
```

I suggest you should check out [thenewboston](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE) java tutorials explaning java for beginners. Good luck!